# Getting error in loading data in pig with year

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-pig

I wan to Write a pig latin script: where I have to load all the data after 1951 (1951 is not included) and Filter the data where quality =1 Group the data by temperature, and then calculate the largest year for each temperature.

did this

```
records = load '/user/a106524609/test.txt' using PigStorage(' ') as 
(year:chararray, temperature:int, quality:int);
rec1 = filter records by year >1951 and (quality == 1);
```

I am getting this error 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading year to a chararray field and comparing it with 1951 which is an int.You have two option.Load the year into an int or else in the filter statement cast the year to int.

```
records = load '/user/a106524609/test.txt' using PigStorage(' ') as 
(year:int, temperature:int, quality:int);
rec1 = filter records by year > 1951 and (quality == 1);
```

Or

```
records = load '/user/a106524609/test.txt' using PigStorage(' ') as 
(year:chararray, temperature:int, quality:int);
rec1 = filter records by year:int > 1951 and (quality == 1);-- Note (int)year > 1951 should work too
```

Comment: now how to Group the data by temperature, and then calculate the largest year for each temperature

Comment: rec2 = group rec1 by year;
maxt = foreach rec2 generate group, MAX(rec1.temperature);

Comment: can you please help me to "Group the data by temperature, and then calculate the largest year for each temperature" @VK_217

Comment: what you have is the opposite.group by temperature and get the max year.rec2 = group rec1 by temperature; maxt = foreach rec2 generate group, MAX((int)rec1.year);